# Google Play version could not be found

Tags: android, google-play

I have been using Google Play in the past, but on a new project I run into a strange problem. I have downloaded GP with SDK Manager and have added it through Project Structure / Dependencies, which added automatically a line in build.gradle dependencies.
But when I do rebuild Project, it fails:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:+.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
     http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
     http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
     file:/Users/thatsme/android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/Users/thatsme/android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
     file:/Users/thatsme/android-sdks/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/Users/thatsme/android-sdks/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
 Required by:
     GA:app:unspecified
```

Comment: Do not ever use `com.google.android.gms:play-services` directly. Use them separately and the latest version is `7.3.0`.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: is means that you can load modular services, and please inform a version. Check: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

add this to manifest

```
<application>
      ...
   <meta-data 
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the SDK Manager and check that you have all necessary packages:

> To develop with Google APIs, you need the Google Play services
>   package: Open the Extras directory and select:
>
> - Google Repository
> - Google Play services

Reference http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

Then:

> To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app:
>
> 1. Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
> 2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services. For example:
>
>    ```
>    dependencies {
>        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
>    }
>    ```
> 3. Save the changes and click Sync Project with Gradle Files  in the toolbar.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

Comment: When I do that, it says:
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0.
Required by:
    GA:app:unspecified

Comment: Check if you also installed the "Google Repository". If not, you also have to install the "Google Repository" in your SDK Manager.